# Vue template shortcut in PhpStorm

Tags: vue.js, phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts

I was watching one of the youtube videos about Vue, and the developer in this video just typed "vue" and got a nice basic Vue template. I suppose he was using VSCode, is there something similar for PhpStorm?

Comment: that was [emmetPlugin](https://www.emmet.io/), see if it works on PhpStorm

Comment: Based on your brief description: you can make your own snippets using Live Templates: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-live-templates.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @LazyOne mentioned, there are snippets already available for Vue, and to get the one I was looking for you need to type `vbase` and press <kbd>tab</kbd>.